# Read log and save it to string

Tags: java, android

I want to read the log and save it to a string inside the app. I use the Log.d(..) to save log. I've read that you use logcat? But that doesn't work when running the android phone. Is there a boolean that you need to switch, READ_LOG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       public static void getLogCatDetails() {
                try {

                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        log.append(line);
                    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
        }

public static void clearLog()
    {
      try
      {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

You have to specify **android.permission.READ_LOGS** permission

Answer (score 0):

Though what KK has written is absolutely correct, but I would suggest that you make use of SharedPreferences to save all your logs because if the user sees some sensitive permissions which he is not able to understand the reason for, it may lead to suspicion and bad ratings for your app.